# code converter not found (ASCII-8BIT to Windows-1258))

Tags: sass, compass-sass

Build scss error

> code converter not found (ASCII-8BIT to Windows-1258))

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just run "chcp 850" before run "gem install".**

Comment: Thanks you so much Arslan Admed Awan